# Should We Replace Link Attributes/Values When We Prevent Default Link Action?

Tags: accessibility, wcag

There are times when I, a custom theme, a contributed module or library, prevents the default action of an `<a>` tag. This is not uncommon and needed when implemented.

Something like `e.preventDefault()`.

Now when you hover over the link, browsers will still show the innate link `href` value, even though the click event is intercepted. Same for bots, scrapers, scripts, anything that reads the DOM.

Examples:

1. Change `href` to `'#'`
2. Change title attribute ('account-menu-list-activator')
3. Add aria-label(s)
4. Or otherwise, alter the link to match it's new UX role.

Does this matter?

Example:

A menu link to a user profile exists in a menu. A new theme/module alters that menu link and adds a `caret` for the dropdown menu. This theme/module looks for this `caret` and alters the behavior of the link via jQuery by intercepting the click event. Now the link no longer redirects to the user profile but toggles the dropdown menu.

This assumes (as is usual) that the `caret` does not have its own click area, and that the `<a>` tag itself is intercepted because of it.

Code Example (Drupal - *Bootstrap Theme*):

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="/user" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link Text <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="first last">
        <a href="/">Sub Link Text</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="last">
    <a href="/">Link Text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`caret` refers to `<span class="caret"></span>`.

This link uses classes and data attributes for functionality/behavior, but does not contain aria labels or replace the href (It's a link, not a button).

Comment: Can you clarifiy what does the link do? If it's not longer a link in the sense that it doesn't redirect you to a new page, but instead starts an action on the same page, then you want to turn it into a `<button>` element. It [can be easily styled](https://fvsch.com/styling-buttons/) to visually _look_ like a link if needed, but in terms of accessibility and usability, it will behave and be announced like a button. If the link has a fallback (if you open it in a new window, does it still work?) then keep it as a link.

Comment: @Victor, I've added an example to my question.

Comment: thanks. I'm not too clear what you mean by `caret` in this instance, but if that new link toggles a dropdown menu then it should definitely be changed to a button instead. Can you provide a screenshot perhaps? If it opens a dropdown menu, you may also want to consider using [`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-expanded) to let screen reader users know that it's expandable, and whether it is currently expanded or not.

Comment: Thanks, @Victor, I've added the markup for a real use case. I feel I would agree strongly with your comment. Can we back it and provide an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Following up on the comments with a more complete answer:

This link no longer has the expected behaviour of a link (taking you to another page), but instead opens a menu on the same page. You should **change it to a native button** element, which will allow you to keep the accessibility benefits (it is keyboard focusable by default, responds to keyboard/touch/mouse events, and interpreted correctly by screen readers and voice command software). You should not use a neutral element (like `<span>` or `<div>`) to replace the link, because by default, that would only work with a mouse without unnecessary additional effort. If you are confused about the semantic difference between a link and a button, see [this blog post](https://uxmovement.com/buttons/when-to-use-a-button-or-link/).

Additionally you should use the [`aria-expanded`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#aria-expanded) attribute on the button, to convey its state to assistive technologies. It should be equal to `false` when it is collapsed, and `true` when it is opened.

In your example, this would look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <button aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Link Text <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="first last">
        <a href="/">Sub Link Text</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="last">
    <a href="/">Link Text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I presume the caret span is an icon of an arrow. Just a small caveat here: it should normally be ignored by screen readers already, because it is an empty span. **However** if that graphic is implemented using an icon font and the CSS ::before pseudo-element, it will become focusable by VoiceOver (it won't be announced as anything, but it will 'click' as a separate element). If that's the case, you can add `aria-hidden="true"` on the caret span, to make sure it is ignored by all screen readers.

**You should only use this technique if the dropdown menu appears on click/key press**, not on hover or on focus. I really recommend [reading this Inclusive Components post](https://inclusive-components.design/menus-menu-buttons/) on menus if your menu is any more complex than that. That post also explains why you should stay away from things like `aria-haspopup` or `role="menu"`, which are often misused and can create a worse experience.

Comment: In this instance, it is a click event. A worthy note about the `::before` pseudo-element. And adding `aria-hidden="true"` to the span element might at least help future proof markup...